# Passing CheckBox Value Via Session in ASP .NET in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, session-variables

I tried so many solusions to this problem without luck, I need to pas a checkbox value from one asp form to another via session variable, but I can't get this simple taks done in ASP .NET. 
In the code behind in form1 I write the code like this:

```
 Session["chkSD_"] = chkSD.Checked;
```

In the ASPX in form2 I do the following:

```
  if(((document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlResponsibility").value == "2") && (document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFinalized") != null && document.querySelectorAll(' <%= Session["chkSD_"] %>)').value))
```

All what I need is to read the value of this check box from previous page.I spent very long time with this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the Session back to a boolean.

```
chkSD.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["chkSD_"]);
```

And writing the Session inline will result in a string value of the boolean, so `<%= Session["chkSD_"] %>` will become `True` or `False` as a string. If you really need javascript to set the checkbox state, you need to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isChecked = '<%= Session["chkSD_"] %>';

    if (isChecked == 'True') {
        //do something
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I assume that the first line of code to be insterted to form1.aspx.cs and the rest in form2.aspx. though this did not work, I still cannot read the <%= Session["chkSD_"] %>' in page2. I try to print to the consol, but it is empty. I just copy paste.

Comment: Try settings the Session manually in page2.cs. Then you can check if the client side is working or not.

Comment: Not sure how to do that? setting the session manually in page2.cs. This is first time I use session and I have no somuch knowledge of it.

Comment: You just do `Session["chkSD_"] = true;` in the 'Page_Load`

Answer (score 0):

Session data isn't directly accessible to the client side. There is one way we can do that. Have a hidden field on form 2. and save the value of session in the hidden field in page load event

```
HiddenField1.Value = Session["chkSD_"].ToString();
```

and then on the second form's client side, get value from the hidden field

```
var val = document.getelementbyid(<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>).value;
```